# how to add the three values of textview and to store in one texview

Tags: android, textview, addition

```
    String s1 = (getIntent().getStringExtra("Value1"));
    String s3 = (getIntent().getStringExtra("value2"));
    String s2 = (getIntent().getStringExtra("value3"));

    id1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id1);
    id2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id2);
    id3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id3);
    id4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id4);

    id1.setText((s1));
    id2.setText((s2));
    id3.setText((s3));
```

How to add the values of the tex view set text values and to store the value as integer in one text view

Comment: you should have tried something first by yourself . adding two values is not a rocket science by the way :) . just take another string add two strings and put their sum in third and then display that string in a textview,

Comment: Actually i tried the simple one it is working but the set text values is not working

Answer (score -1):

```
id1.setText((s1));
id2.setText((s2));
id3.setText((s3));
```

then your question, add the three values of textview and to store in one texview

```
int first = Integer.parseInt(id1.getText().toString());
int second = Integer.parseInt(id2.getText().toString());
int third = Integer.parseInt(id3.getText().toString());
int final = first+second+third;

id4.setText(""+final);
```

Comment: what? why downvote? the question is clearly want to add the three values of textview and to store in one texview..